# which language choose for server side programming laravel or nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I know Html, CSS, javascript, bootstrap so I wanted to move on now I am confused which server side language to choose I learned basic PHP. I have a project to complete which has real-time collaboration, file uploads etc. Now I wanted to learn and complete my project within 2or3 months. Need some suggestion. TIA

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. Whatever you chose, it will work just fine.

Comment: I agree with adeneo but It's highly improbable that a novice alone can complete (_I mean "complete" with success_) a project with that requirements from scratch in only 2/3 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can create real-time applications using PHP, Node.js is "naturally" a better fit for this kind of application. Besides that as you said that you are choosing a new language to learn, I suggest you to see which one is becoming more expressive and that will probably have more attraction on the market from now on. The Developers Survey from Stack Overflow is a good source of information for you to start this research.

**2017:**
https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#most-popular-technologies

**2016:**
https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016#technology-most-popular-technologies

As a basis for what I said about Node.js and real-time applications:

**Why the Hell Would You Use Node.js**

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/why-the-hell-would-you-use-node-js-4b053b94ab8e

> Where Node.js really shines is in building fast, scalable network
>   applications, as it’s capable of handling a huge number of
>   simultaneous connections with high throughput, which equates to high
>   scalability. How it works under-the-hood is pretty interesting.
>   Compared to traditional web-serving techniques where each connection
>   (request) spawns a new thread, taking up system RAM and eventually
>   maxing-out at the amount of RAM available, Node.js operates on a
>   single-thread, using non-blocking I/O calls, allowing it to support
>   tens of thousands of concurrent connections (held in the event loop).

**What aspects of Node.js make it suitable for real-time web applications?**

https://www.quora.com/What-aspects-of-Node-js-make-it-suitable-for-real-time-web-applications

And here goes some suggestions for your adventure:

- https://socket.io/
- http://restify.com/#socketio

Comment: This really boosts my confidence and I will go for node js.